# Laravel 5 returns 404 error for every page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I am having trouble configuring Apache and my project's .htaccess file. I am storing it in a subfolder in /var/www/html, and aliasing it via Apache. I have also added RewriteBase to my .htaccess file. Accessing to the alias (server.ip/blog) lists the public directory, but everything I try to access returns a 404 error. Any ideas?

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
RewriteBase /blog/
```

Apache site .conf:

```
Alias /blog/ "/var/www/html/exoblog/public" 

<Directory "/var/www/html/exoblog/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mymail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/exoblog/public"
    ServerName eneko.dev
    ServerAlias www.eneko.dev
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/exob.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/exob.log" common

<Directory "/var/www/html/exoblog/public">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add all the code

Comment: Did you added it in a host file??

Comment: What do you mean?? It is located in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/blog.conf

Comment: https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp See if you have followed all the steps from the link given

Comment: yup already had done that, I updated my answer with the VirtualHost

Comment: shouldnt the directory path be full starting with the drive

Comment: In a Ubuntu server, I don't think so (its a valid route, no need to specify any drive)

Comment: Check the apache error log, `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, remove the slash from `/index.php`, and move your `RewriteBase` up:

Your `.htaccess` file should be saved in your `blog` directory and should contain the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`Options +FollowSymlinks` does not need to be in that file as the configuration already has it set up.

If you are using Apache 2.4 (as opposed to 2.2), your virtual host `<directory...>` should look like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/exoblog/public">
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Also, this does not need to be duplicated in the `conf` file.

Comment: Ok so I just made these changes, I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error. Any idea why?

Comment: What version of Apache are you running?

Comment: I'm running version 2.4.7

Comment: Please check the error log at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: I got this: `AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`